# how i can delete last separator , from echo

Tags: php

I have problems because I can't delete last, from my echo

with rtrim

```
  while($t= mysql_fetch_array($asd)){
    $rest = '
       "'.$t['a'].'": "'.$t['b'].'",';
    echo rtrim($rest,",");
```

output:

```
   "1": "a"
   "2": "b"
   "3": "a"
   "4": "b"
```

how I can achieve like this:

output:

```
   "1": "a",
   "2": "b",
   "3": "a",
   "4": "b"
```

I arleady trying with some `rtrim`,`explode` etc but its doesnt work

I arleady trying with rtrim
this doesnt work here is my code:

```
 while($t= mysql_fetch_array($asd)){
$str = '
   "'.$t['a'].'": "'.$t['b'].'",';
    echo rtrim($str, ",");
```

Comment: are you trying to generate json?

Comment: use rtrim($string, ',')

Comment: Two ways. Options A is to modify your loop to check if the current element is the last element, if so, don't add the `,` in the first place. Option B is to simply strip the `,` after you are done, see for example [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: and for using `end()`, you are creating a string,  not an array, and you overwrite the value of `$rest` in every loop instead of appending?

Comment: check my answer given below

Comment: `preg_replace('/,$/', '', $str );`

Comment: Please answer robert's question. Are you trying to generate JSON? If yes, do you know about the `json_decode` and `json_encode` functions?

Comment: Oh, by the way, `mysql` is deprecated, you should use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: If you are trying to get json, first build the array structure you need and then use `json_encode()` to get valid json. And use a modern database api like PDO or mysqli to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use php `rtrim()` function to remove the `,` from the right. The `rtrim()` function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.

```
echo rtrim($rest,",");//remove all the , from right
```

or, use `substr()` function of php to remove the last character

```
echo substr($rest,0,strlen($rest)-1);// remove the last character only
```

Comment: thank, but this doenst work because it remove all , from my output look    "1": "a"
   "2": "b"
   "3": "a"
   "4": "b"

Comment: @DawidWiewiór thanks, i edited my answer, check the second one

Comment: thanks guys for help now working :). your code is better because just one line :)

Answer (score 3):

From what i see is that you are trying to generate a json object, this is not the way to do that.

```
$data = [];
while (($t = mysql_fetch_array($asd))) {
    $data[$t['a']] = $t['b'];
}

echo json_decode($data);
```

This will output a json string in the format you are trying to generate.

---

Sidenote 1:

The reason your rtrim in your code is not working is because you rtrim every line in the while loop, not the last line. But since you use `$rest =` you are also overwriting the value of `$rest` in every iteration.

---

Sidenote 2:

What @jeroen is saying in the comments, **do not** use `mysql_fetch_array`, these methods have been deprecated for some time. Look for PDO, mysqli or use a php framework with a proper ORM.

Comment: This is  better way to create json .good move

Answer (score 1):

Besides rtrim you can use `substr()` to remove the last character:

```
while ($something) {
    //construct $str
}
$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do on single string, but right now you are doing it on every string instance in while loop,

```
$str = '';
while($t= mysql_fetch_array($asd)){
   $str .= '
   "'.$t['a'].'": "'.$t['b'].'",';

}

$str = rtrim($str,",");
```

Give it a try, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$rest = '';
while($t= mysql_fetch_array($asd)){
  $rest .= ' "'.$t['a'].'": "'.$t['b'].'",';  
}

$rest = rtrim($rest,",");
echo $rest;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just to throw in an alternative solution:**
You could not attach the trailing comma in the first place instead of trimming it afterwards.

Let's assume you have the number of results in `$num_rows`, then you could do:

```
$i = 1;
while($t = mysql_fetch_array($asd)) {
    $rest = '"' . $t['a'] . '": "' . $t['b'] . (($i==$num_rows) ? '"' : '",');
    ++$i;
}
echo $rest;
```

Of course, note what some other answers pointed out: your `echo` was *in* the loop, but should stand outside of the loop.

**Please also note** that you are using the deprecated `mysql` extension; you should use `mysqli` instead. See the note in the PHP docs:

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.